# need to write powershell script to clear the recycle bin using if else statement

Tags: powershell, scripting

if ((c:$RECYCLE.BIN).Count -ne 0 ){
Remove-Item $RECYCLEBIN -Confirm
write-host " its empty "}

else { ((c:$RECYCLE.BIN).Count -eq 0 )
"FOLDER IS EMPTY"
}

while try this to empty the recycle bin am getting error as
c:$RECYCLE.BIN : The term 'c:$RECYCLE.BIN' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:6

- if ((c:$RECYCLE.BIN).Count -ne 0 ){
- ```
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:$RECYCLE.BIN:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Recycle Bin is a special folder, so use [Clear-RecycleBin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/clear-recyclebin?view=powershell-7.2) cmdlet instead

Comment: Is there any code missing as i cant see where you define `$RECYCLE`? as @vonPryz mentioned, use `Clear-RecycleBin`

Comment: @Otter Windows' Recycle bin is a system directory named `$Recycle.Bin`, so there's a dollar though it isn't related to PS variable.

Comment: please add proper code formatting markers around your code & errors.